# Jquery Selector not able to find div element in Polymer. Should be straightforward Not understanding the Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, polymer

**Objective:** On click of a icon inside a form I want to add a new class to the div containing the form.
**Problem:** Jquery selector in pullupClose is not picking the element. [Console.log result of Jquery sector in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSJzS.png) As the element is only not getting fetched hence addAclass does'nt work.
 **Can you please figure out the mistake I am doing?** Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidepullup" id="idSidePullup">
            <iron-icon class="cross" on-click="pullupClose" icon="close"></iron-icon>
            <iron-form id="idForm">
                <form action="/">
                    <paper-input type"text" label="First Name"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input type="text" label="Last Name"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input type="text" label="Title"></paper-input>
                    <paper-input type="text" label="About"></paper-input>
                    <paper-button style="background-color: #03a9f4; color: white" raised onclick="onFormSubmit()">Submit Changes</paper-button>
                </form>
            </iron-form>
         </div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        class IronListClass extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {return 'iron-comp'}
        ready() {
                super.ready();
                var that = this;
            }
            pullupClose() {
                var element = $("#idSidePullup");
                console.log('console log of $("#idSidePullup") = ', element);
                $("#idSidePullup").addClass('hidePullup');
                $("#idSidePullup").css("display", "none");
            }
window.customElements.define(IronListClass.is, IronListClass);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to target the Polymer dom first.

```
var element = $(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#idSidePullup'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks lot man. It worked!! didn't know this is how you do in Polymer. This can be closed now :)